# adding aliases for the new user after sudo'ing interactive from a script

Tags: bash

I was following the instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135644/how-can-i-define-a-bash-alias-as-a-sequence-of-multiple-commands to create my own bash script. It is as follows:

```
sudo -u otheruser -i
alias cd1="cd /dir/one/"
alias cd2="cd /dir/two/"
```

I want these aliases to be available to `otheruser`. My goal is to run it as an executable but for testing I am sourcing it (to avoid the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197461/how-to-set-an-alias-inside-a-bash-shell-script-so-that-is-it-visible-from-the-ou) like `source ./myscript`.

Even with doing that, the sudo works, but none of the following aliases are available (for `otheruser`). Do you think the aliases are being applied to the user that invoked this command, and not to the new user? Or is there some rule that commands in a script are ignored after sudo'ing to another user?

Comment: Add this to `/etc/profile` (can depends of your distro)

Comment: Or `~otheruser/.profile`

Comment: I am not sure that either of those ideas will work. I am intentionally not adding it to `~otheruser/.profile` because I don't want it to take effect whenever that other user logs in (I don't want to interfere with that user). I only want to enable these commands when I sudo as that user, by running my script. // As for adding this to `/etc/profile` if by that you mean my own login script, I don't see how that will help because I want the commands to be available when I'm sudo'd as the other user.

Comment: If you need just to alias `cd` command you can use the `autojump` command just `j one` to `cd /dir/one` see here : [autojump on github](https://github.com/wting/autojump)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason it doesn't work is that the two `alias` commands
are run after `bash` session started by `sudo` finishes.  You could
make a test - source the script, when the new session starts press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> to leave it and then in the original shell type:

```
$ type cd1
cd1 is aliased to `cd /dir/one/'
$ type cd2
cd2 is aliased to `cd /dir/two/'
```

I can achieve what you want with [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script but I'm not an expert
on that so criticism is welcome:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn sudo -u otheruser -i
send "alias cd1='cd /dir/one/'"
send "\n"
send "alias cd2='cd /dir/two/'"
send "\n"

interact
```

Make sure you actually have `expect` installed before running this
script.

You might be able to install `expect` and `tcl` (which it requires) using your system's package manager. If you need to install it manually, see the instructions for Expect at http://expect.sourceforge.net/. The README/INSTALL files for Expect point you at some locations for getting Tcl, but these seem out of date. However you can get a copy of Tcl from ActiveState.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't have `expect`. I downloaded it and was going to install it, but it also requires `tcl` and I don't want to install that as well so I'm going to skip it for now.

Comment: Why not? It doesn't take much space. It won't break anything, too. BTW, what distro do you use?

Comment: It's just a lot of time expenditure for this task since it was just a little annoyance I wanted to solve, not a core issue for a project. I'm using Red Hat at work but we don't have permission to install new packages. I did extract expect to a folder in my user directory and extracted ActiveState's Tcl Linux distro to another folder (so they are side-by-side like it requested) but it wasn't able to find it.

Comment: `-bash-4.1$ ./configure
checking for correct TEA configuration... ok (TEA 3.9)
configure: configuring expect 5.45.4
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions`

Comment: OK I hadn't installed it. So I installed Tcl and added it to my path, but the configure command still can't find it. Tcl is in `/home/user/sdewey/expect/activestate_tcl` and expect is in `/home/user/myuser/expect/expect5.45.4` but going into the latter directory and running ./configure it can't find tcl.

Comment: Do you have `tclConfig.sh`?

Comment: `./configure --help` mentions: `--with-tcl              directory containing tcl configuration (tclConfig.sh)`

Comment: Do you have a working `expect` binary? If you do remember you have to change `shebang line` from `/usr/bin/expect` to point to the `expect` you just compiled or run the script `expect script`.

Comment: OK, I finished testing it and it works! Surprising there isn't an easier way, but thank you for helping me find this way. `expect` seems like a cool tool, maybe I will look into it more later.

Comment: Cool, I am glad I could help!

Comment: btw why do you use `\r` instead of `\n` or something?

Comment: I really didn't give it a much thought as they are interchangeable in this context but you're right that `\n` would be *Unixy* and natural here. I will change it.